How do programmers distribute their games from custom game engines?
I am currently reading tons of books about game engine, real time rendering, animation, physics... but I could not find any description of how game developers who built their game with their own game engine are able to create a file (an executable file) containing the game and not all the game engine tools they use with it.
Is this just a matter of a macro parameter specifying the type of build they create?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The room has been frozen before I got the occasion to get back to you; but I started a very early embryo of this here.

I'm going to use the ID Software engines as an example here, because all of their older engines (up to and including Doom 3) have had their source code made available under the GNU GPL, so you can read it, study it, understand it, and learn from it.
This of course comes with the caveat that these - particularly the really old engines - are not exactly shining examples of modern best practice, and you shouldn't expect them to be.
I won't go through each engine in detail, but I will instead discuss 2 engines, which provide examples of two different approaches.  These are all available at the ID Software Github.
Quake 2
This is an example of having separate Engine and Tools.  A file format - for example a map file - is defined via standard C/C++ structs, and two separate codebases are written using that file format.  The tools build the final binary file that the engine consumes from source files, and the two codebases don't actually have much duplication of code.  Excluding the Tools is simply a matter of just not shipping them, as they are completely separate executables.
Doom 3
The Tools are integrated into the Engine.  This allows the Tools to be launched from a development console, and while they can share code, in practice they don't really because the Tools use some unoptimized (and simpler) code that would be unsuitable for the Engine.  The Tools can also be excluded from a build via some #defines, if required.
